# Creating HIVE External Table from read-only folder

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, external

I have access to Hadoop cluster where I have **read-only** access to hdfs folder where the data is (in this case /data/table1/data_PART0xxx). I would like to build a HIVE EXTERNAL Table which would provide me easier way to query the data.

So, I created a table as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myDB.Table1 (column1 STRING, column2 STRING, column3 STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 "input.regex" = "(.{10})(.{16})(.{10})"
 )
LOCATION '/data/table1';
```

However, it gives me error:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: user [my_user] does not have [ALL] privilege on [hdfs://hadoopcluster/data/table1] (state=42000,code=40000)

which I understand, I don't have right to write anything, but how can I do this, so that the table is explicitly defined as read-only?

Edit: I know I can set it as *CREATE TEMPORARY EXTERNAL TABLE ...*  but I would like to have a bit more permanent solution. Further, I have also no privileges to set the folder /data/table1 to mode 777. Isn't there a way to tell HIVE, this table is meant only to be queried, no further data will be added (at least not through HIVE).

Edit: Further, I have seen [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-335) for this since 2009 set to important, but still not resolved.